# Fatal Error Maximum Time Execution, in API Requst, I php

Tags: php, curl, httprequest, fatal-error, php-curl

I do some API request use `php(cURL)`, but I have problem in `cURL_exec()`, for some case it always Fatal error max. execution. How to fix it? really need help

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 500); //500 seconds
```

Comment: Please add some information on why this could fix the OPs problem

Comment: WordPress last version By default  limits maximum execution time is 30 seconds.. that why gives you a problem..

Add the following code to .htaccess if you dont wanna work with PHP script: php_value max_execution_time 5000000
 will work.. hope :)

Comment: Dont add information as comment. Edit your answer instead!

Comment: If you edit your answer to include the information from your comment, it would actually be a decent answer.

Answer (score 0):

there may be several different time limits at play here, first, when running php outside of cli mode, there's usually a `php max execution time` limit, which you can change with the [set_time_limit() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), if you're running php behind fpm, there's usually fpm read timeout with whatever fpm client you're using (eg, for nginx+php-fpm, you'd need to change nginx's `fastcgi_read_timeout` variable), and the curl api itself has timeouts on how long curl_exec is allowed to run, called `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`, which you can edit with the [`curl_setopt()` function.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: i have try CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT and CURLOPT_TIMEOUT but the result just same, any idea?

Comment: @febrisaputro dunno. how are you running PHP? as an apache plugin? (eg mod_php), or over fpm? (eg, nginx+php-fpm), or from CLI perhaps?